# Qual o significado da palavra "formosa" no tempo dos Descobrimentos?

Tags: significado

Em Taiwan, também conhecida como ilha Formosa, é ensinado nas escolas que esta palavra significa especificamente "bonita/linda", traduzindo do chinês.
No entanto, eu já procurei em dicionários modernos de língua portuguesa, e refere-se sempre a ser uma mulher com uma forma agradável, o que difere do conceito de "bonita".

O poema de Camões, escrito no tempo dos Descobrimentos, utiliza a palavra "formosa":

> Descalça vai para a fonte
>   Descalça vai para a fonte Leonor pela verdura;
>   Vai formosa e não segura.

Que significado tinha nesse período histórico?

Answer (score 10):

O sufixo [OSA/OSO](http://www.ocsan.net/gramatica/grafia/ort7.htm) significa "*cheio de*" e dá a ideia de plenitude:

- Rancorosa = Cheia de rancor
- Humorosa = [Muito humorada](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/humoroso).
- Formosa = [Perfeita, deleitosa, de formas ou feições agradáveis](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/formoso) e daí se tira a *ideia de com muitas formas agradáveis*.

Eu não percebo porque é que você afirma que ter formas agradáveis é diferente de ser bonita.

- Bonita = [Que é agradável à vista](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bonita).
- Formosa = [De formas ou feições agradáveis](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/formoso)

As definições são muito parecidas embora formosa signifique cheia de formas e, óbvio, compara-se a mulher ao violão exatamente pelas formas e por se achar bonito as formas.

Indo muito ao limite, diria que bonita pode substituir formosa sempre... mas que formosa tenderia a ser usada mais para algo fisico como corpo de uma mulher ou uma ilha.

Soaria estranho se ela tivesse um formoso "coração" mas já acharíamos normal se ela tivesse um bonito "coração", tendo coração do sentido de maneira de ser.

Comment: A palavra chinesa usada em Taiwan, para descrever "formosa", nome dado pelos Portugueses à 500 anos atrás é 漂亮, esta palavra significa especificamente bonita, pode ser utilizada relativamente a uma paisagem ou uma mulher. Mas quando utilizado para referir uma mulher, refere-se especificamente à beleza física. Há outras palavras chinesas para de formas agradáveis que não esta, mas esta descreve algo mais especifico. Fazendo-me pensar que à 500 anos atrás teria um significado diferente.

Comment: formosa também diz respeito ao jeito de ser